# TypeError: v2.register is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, angularjs-controller

Сама ошибка:

> TypeError: v2.register is not a function

My Form:

```
<div class="homepopup" ng-controller="RegisterController">
            <div class="title">Sign Up <span>to</span> Get Jobs</div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="form">
                    <div class="padding">
                        <div class="line icon-tel">
                            <div>
                                <span>CELL NUMBER:</span>
                                <input type="number" class="tel" name="tel" required ng-model="customer.tel" minlength="10" value="" placeholder="Min. length 10" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="line icon-pwd-lock">
                            <div>
                                <span>PASSWORD:</span>
                                <input type="password" name="password" required ng-model="customer.pass" minlength="4" value="" placeholder="Min. length 4"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="line icon-pwd-green">
                            <div>
                                <span>CONFIRM PASSWORD:</span>
                                <input type="password" name="repassword" required ng-model="customer.repass" minlength="4" value="" placeholder="Min. length 4" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="button_blue" ng-click="register(customer)">CREATE USER</div>
            </div>
            <div class="copyright">
                <div>
                    By porceeding, you agree to BookJobsNow <br> <a href="">Term of Service</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;and&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="">Privacy Policy</a>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

My Controller:

```
angular.module('api').controller('RegisterController', ['$scope', 'Register', '$location', '$ionicPopup', function($scope, Register, $location, $ionicPopup) {
    $scope.valid = true;

    $scope.register = function(customer) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(customer);

        if($scope.master.tel != undefined && $scope.master.pass != undefined && $scope.master.repass != undefined) {
            if($scope.master.pass != $scope.master.repass) {
                $ionicPopup.alert({title: 'Register failed!', template: "Password does not match the confirm password." });
                $scope.valid = false;
            }
        }

        if($scope.valid) {
            $scope.register = new Register($scope.master.tel, $scope.master.pass);
            $scope.register.success(function(data) {
                var json = angular.fromJson(data);
                console.log(json);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

В чем может быть проблема? При первом нажатии все прекрасно отрабатывает. Если еще раз нажать, то выдаёт ERROR.

Есть подобная функция только Login, с ней всё нормально, с неё делался копипаст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помоему ты вызываеш функцию нажатим кнопки "$scope.register = function(customer)". А внутри неё меняеш значение "$scope.register" на объект "$scope.register = new Register()". Поэтому при повторном нажатии кнопки функции register уже не существует. Понэменяй название объекта который получаеш с конструктора на что-то другое

Comment: Спасибо. Я думал при вызове переопределяет и не придавал потом этому значение.